# Can the FDR be interfered with in-flight?

Tags: flight-data-recorder, mh370-incident

Can an FDR on a Boeing 777 be interfered with or vandalised during flight?

If this has happened on MH370 then the black boxes may not yield any data if found.

Comment: you can pull the fuses of the black boxes, this may set off an alarm depending on the craft though